# Filter on specific column and delete all data with future date

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to VBA/Macros... I want the macro to filter on a column named "ABC" and delete all data with a future date. For example, today's date 10/8/2020 which macro should check and delete all data with a future date. Example In below excel screen macro should delete the data having date 10\10\2020 which is greater than today's date and retain data having a date 10\04\2020 which is past.

I tried coding in many ways but nothing works out. Below is the lastest code I tried which failed.

```
 Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()

Dim row As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim mindate As Date
Dim maxdate As Date
Dim st As Worksheet

'Column Name 
cons = "Vessel Estimated Time of Departure"
st = Worksheet("POL")

mindate = CDate(Cells(1, 10))
maxdate = CDate(Cells(1, 12))

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("POL").lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "cons").End(xlUp).row
row = 1 'Set here the starting row for checking transaction dates
Do While row <= lastrow
transdate = CDate(Cells(row, 3))
    If transdate < mindate Or transdate > maxdate Then
        Rows(row).EntireRow.Delete
    Else
        row = row + 1
    End If
Loop

End Sub
```

All I want is the macro filter on a column named "Vessel Estimated Time of Departure" and remove all the data with a future date by default from the current system date.

Comment: Use `Range.AutoFilter` instead of looping. You can easily apply a time filter. Once the data is filtered, you can then delete the visible rows.

Comment: something new how do I do that

Comment: Use the macro recorder or search for similar questions here on SO. There are a lot of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar, but this code does a check in each cell value for found column based on string.

if there is a date greater than today's date, it will mark the cell with an "x"

the function deltR will remove ENTIREROW of any cell that contains x mark on found col.

Give it a try and let me know if you have any questions,

Please see script below:

```
Option Explicit

Dim wb As Workbook

Dim sRng As Range
Dim fRng As Range

Dim cel As Range

Dim tRow As Long
Dim fCol As Long


Dim tDate As String




Sub foo()
    
    'setting wb as thisworkbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    'row 1 assigned into fRng(find range) object
    Set fRng = wb.Sheets("POL").Rows(1).Find(what:="Vessel Estimated Time of Departure", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    
    'gets fRng range object, and assigns its column property value into fCol variable
    fCol = fRng.Column
    

    'finding the last row for column 1, make sure you select a col that covers the whole data set, based on last row
    tRow = wb.Sheets("POL").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'assigning range based on col index based on str search(fCol) + total row count (tRow) in sRng range object
    'sRng range object is being used to search for dates above todays date (DATE())
    With wb.Sheets("POL")
    
        Set sRng = .Range(.Cells(2, fCol), .Cells(tRow, fCol))
    
    End With
    
    'obtains current date and formats into mmddyyyy format
    tDate = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    
    'performs a cell loop value check based on found column above "vessel (...) departure..."
    For Each cel In sRng
    
        If Trim(Format(cel.Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")) > tDate Then
            'marks any date greater than today() date with an "x"
            cel.Value = "x"
        
        Else
        End If
        
    Next cel
    
    Set sRng = Nothing
    
    
    With wb.Sheets("POL")
    
        Set sRng = .Range(.Cells(1, fCol), .Cells(tRow, fCol))
    
    End With
    
    'function deltR will remove any cel in found col with has "x" value, where "x" equals to cells that had date greater than DATE() (today)
    'passing arguments: range (sRng), delete anything marked with "x"
    Call deltR(sRng, "x", 1)


End Sub





Private Sub deltR(ByRef sRng As Range, ByVal aStr As String, ByVal f As Integer)

    'this sub procedure looks for a string (aStr) passed in (sRng) range object range, based on col number (f)
    With sRng

        .AutoFilter field:=f, Criteria1:=aStr
        .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete

    End With

    wb.Sheets("POL").AutoFilterMode = False

    Set sRng = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect Thanks @ Victor song Thanks a lot thanks for explaining the codes to...